# Translating assembled IJVM code to Java code

Tags: java, stack, hex

I am so frustrated. I have translated this hex code to IJVM assembly language, but I can not for the life of me figure out how to put it all together in java format.

```
I am using I as local variable 1, j as local variable 2 and k as local variable 3.

Iload I 0x15 0x01   
Iload j 0x15 0x02    
DUP 0x59 (copy J onto the stack again)    
iadd 0x60 (add j+j or 2*j)   
isub 0x64 (I- (j+j))  
ifeq 0x99 0x00 0x05 (***)
bipush 42 0x10 0x2A  
Istore k 0x36 0x03
```

*** This is where I start to get confused... I know this is an if statement to see if a number is equal to zero. I am not sure what the else statement would be though.  Any help would be GREATLY appreciated!

Here is what I'm getting...

```
if ((I-(j+j) == 0) 
k=42;
```

Answer (score 1):

The syntax for IFEQ has a 16-bit offset. The offset is added to the PC at the start of the instruction

```
0x99 0x00 0x05
```

means to jump over 5 bytes, if the test is zero. Jump over the 3 bytes of the instruction itself and the next two bytes that follow it.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I came up with. Assume this .java file (note: there may be a slight difference in JVM to IJVM):

```
class test 
{
    public static void main(String args)
{
    int k = 1;
    int j = 2;
    int n;

        if (j - (k + k) != 0);
        n = 42;
    }
}
```

When compiled and disassembled here is the result:

```
C:\java\sample>javap -c test
Compiled from "test.java"
class test {
  test();
    Code:
       0: aload_0
       1: invokespecial #1         // Method java/lang/Object."<init>":()V
       4: return

  public static void main(java.lang.String);
    Code:
       0: iconst_1
       1: istore_1
       2: iconst_2
       3: istore_2
       4: iload_2
       5: iload_1
       6: iload_1
       7: iadd
       8: isub
       9: ifeq          12
      12: bipush        42
      14: istore_3
      15: return
}
```